# QFile::remove not removing file?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfile, qdir

Having a strange problem when trying to remove a file i just downloaded with Qt.

My code:

```
QString location = "/path/to/app/Application.app";
QFile *rmFile = new QFile(location);
rmFile->remove();
```

File is not being removed.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Always check the return value. Cause could be permission or locking by being in use or wrong path.

Comment: What does the return value of the remove call? See `if(!rmFile->remove()) qDebug() << rmFile.errorString();` Also, in this special case, the instance is an overkill. You can call the static method directly.

Comment: If you are under Mac, "/path/to/app/Application.app" points to a directory, and not to the file, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a directory as it seems to be, you wish to use the following API with Qt 5:

> [bool QDir::removeRecursively()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively)

as opposed to `QFile`. Therefore, you would be writing something like this:

```
QString location = "/path/to/app/Application.app";
QDir *rmDir = new QDir(location);
rmDir->removeRecursively();
```

Note that I would not personally use a heap object just for this. Stack object would suffice in this simple case.